# selenium vba-set reference to existing chrome browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the following code works fine in creating a new browser and inputting data in a textbox.

```
Dim sw As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
sw.Start "Chrome", "http://www.yahoo.com"
sw.setTimeout ("120000")
sw.setImplicitWait (5000)
sw.Open "www.yahoo.com"
sw.Type "name=p", "Eiffel tower"
sw.Click "name=btnG"
```

However, for certain sites, i first need to manually login and then, i would like to execute the selenium-vba code, to fill in relevant relevant textboxes. can someone kindly provide an example where i am able to set reference to existing browser/webpage?

thks ken

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is not possible to connect Selenium to a previously open browser.  Having said that, if you give us examples of sites you haven't managed to automate the login for, we can probably help you get past whatever issues you've been having.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to have VBA initiate the browser, then pause while you enter your credentials, then resume.

```
sub Login()
 Dim sw As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
 sw.Start "Chrome", "http://www.yahoo.com"
 sw.setTimeout ("120000")
 sw.setImplicitWait (5000)
 sw.Open "your site"

 msgbox "Login now and click OK when done."

 'your code here

end sub
```